# BlackBerry 10 Dev Apha Simulator Size Issue

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to do some magic with BB. So I decided to go with BlackBerry Cascades. For that I downloaded Native SDK (772 MB) and Simulator (242 MB) and Photsjop plug in. I installed Native SDk and simulator and I opened the Simualtor in Vm.

Till here there is no issues., but when Simulator opens Size of Simulator is too large like there are scrollers to see the complete Simulator. How to fix the size of simulator with according to the vmware size.

I changed the Value in Controllers.exe, but it doesn’t get differences. So please let me know, how to solve this issue.

Comment: please make sure your controller is connected with vmware/simulator;
after that you can change zoom level of simulator/vmware

Answer (score 3):

Hi You can resize you Vmware simulator according to your monitor screen size.following is the steps for that.
1. Go to where the simulator Vmware is installed (in my case: C:\Users\\Documents\Virtual Machines\BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_0_06)

1. Go to the "controllers" folder
2. Run "controller.exe"
3. Select Connection > Connect
4. Type the simulator's IP address and press Connect  (verify it says "Connected to 192.168.xxx.xxx" on the bottom of the screen)
5. Go to Device > Change Zoom Level; enter 40% or percentage then Apply.

Comment: thank you for your reply Megha, I did the changes as you said, i can able change the Zoom Level, but there is no change in simulator because of this. I am using windows 7 64 bit, Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: same issue on  Window7 & Ubuntu, no any change in simulator

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes controller doesn't work as you expect. 

I use following way to change simulator's zoom. Connect to the simulator using telnet with login/password **devuser/devuser**. Then put the command 
**`ves-zoom <zoom_value>`** 

Where zoom_value is the percentage value of desired zoom.

Look at [Simulator Configuring](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_configuring.html) to clarify.